# Ajax call not working on search query

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, api, reactjs

I have a github profile viewer react application which allows you search a profile by username. In the default state I have provided my own github username so that the landing page is my own github profile. You can search for a profile by entering the name in the search bar, but my `ajax` call is not working whenever i try to search for a user, however the same function is returning valid data for my own username. The error that I am getting is as follows:-

> Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax is not a function

My main App.jsx class is as follows

```
class App extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: 'kinny94',
            userData: [],
            userRepos: [],
            perPage: 5 
        } 
    }

    getUserData(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.github.com/users/' + this.state.username + '?client_id=' + this.props.clientId + '&client_secret=' + this.props.clientSecret,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                this.setState({
                    userData: data
                });
                console.log(data);
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err){
                this.setState({
                    username: null
                });
                alert(err);
            }.bind(this)
         });
    }

    getUserRepos(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.github.com/users/' + this.state.username + '/repos?per_page='+ this.state.perPage +'client_id=' + this.props.clientId + '&client_secret=' + this.props.clientSecret + '&sort=created',
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function(data){
                this.setState({
                    userRepos: data
                });
            }.bind(this),
            error: function(xhr, status, err){
                this.setState({
                    username: null
                });
                alert(err);
            }.bind(this)
        });
    }

    handleformSubmit(username){
        this.setState({
            username: username
        }, function(){
            this.getUserData();
            this.getUserRepos();
        })
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.getUserData();
        this.getUserRepos();
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Search onFormSubmit={this.handleformSubmit.bind(this)}/>
                <Profile {...this.state}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

and  my search file is as follows

```
class Search extends Component{

    onSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let username = this.refs.username.value.trim();
        if(!username){
            alert('Please Enter a username!');
            return;
        }

        this.props.onFormSubmit(username);
        this.refs.username.value = '';
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)}>
                    <label>Search Github Users </label>
                    <input type="text" ref="username" className="form-control" />
                </form> 
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

My question is, if the same `ajax` call working for my username, why it isn't working of a new random username.

Comment: Just a suggestion. You are loading JQUERY just make an api call via ajax, you can use other lightweight libraries like axios or superagent or the fetch api if your sole purpose is to make api calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. I was using the both the `slim` and `compressed` regular version of `jquery`. `ajax` is not in the `slim` version of `jquery`, so I just removed it and used regular `jquery` instead. worked like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to include `jquery` script in your html.

Something like this in your html:

```
<script src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I already have that. If I didn't have that, I wouldn't even get the result for my own username.

Comment: @Then there has to be some error in the url. Also it is advisable to add the type of call in the request.

Comment: @Pritam Banerjee  i added ajax add to cart button in my bigcommerce website it work on home and product page but it not work on only search result page

```<script
         src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
         integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
         crossorigin="anonymous">
       </script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css">
       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>```